# How to check if an element of @_ is read-only in a Perl sub?

Tags: perl, parameters, readonly, subroutine

When my sub needs to pass back some output thru one of the parameters (return value is already used to pass back another output), a run-time error occurs when that parameter holds a constant from the caller.  Example:

```
# Increases the input by 1 and reports if the new value is bigger than 10.
sub IncreaseByOne {
    $_[0] ++;
    return ($_[0] > 10 ? 1 : 0);
}

my $x = 1;
IncreaseByOne($x);  # This is OK.
IncreaseByOne(1);   # This is not OK.
```

My question: Is there a way within the sub to tell if $_[0] is read only?  (I understand that many would say it is not a good practice to return information thru one of parameters.  But I really need to in my situation.)

Comment: Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings` turned on?

Comment: Hoping for a cleaner way than eval.  Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Re "*I understand that many would say it is not a good practice to return information thru one of parameters*", I would actually say it's not a good practice to check if the parameter is readonly; a bad argument already results in an error.

Comment: Ikegami -- what is wrong with readonly() fuction suggested by Amon (below)?   I agree with you that one should avoid triggering an error and then cleaning up the mess with eval.  But unless readonly() is doing eval behind the scene, I do not see any thing "bad".

Comment: @ShangZhang what is wrong is exactly what Amon says: "If the sub is supposed to increment the value, then it should fail if that's not possible: don't surprise users by silently ignoring a problem. That error is a good thing!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the sub is supposed to increment the value, then it should fail if that's not possible: don't surprise users by silently ignoring a problem. That error is a good thing!

But if really necessary, you can test whether the scalar is [readonly](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util#readonly):

```
use Scalar::Util 'readonly';

sub IncreaseByOne {
  readonly($_[0]) or $_[0]++;
  ...
}
```

Note that instead of using out-parameters (which leads to unexpected problems like you experienced), it is often better to return a list of multiple values:

```
sub IncreaseByOne {
  my ($x) = @_;
  $x++;
  my $more_than_ten = ($x > 10);
  return $x, $more_than_ten;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amon.  I do return an array (or ref to an array) 95% of time.  But I really had to do it this way this time.  Thanks for showing the Scalar::Util::readonly() function!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to use Scalar::Util::readonly doesn't completely solve the issue.
I have the following use case:

```
sub Lookup {
  # Get a value from a table, file, or database, using the label in $_[0].
  # Set $_[1] to that value if that parameter is writable.
  # Return an error code or a success code.
  my $value = get_value_from_somewhere($_[0]);
  my $error = get_error_from_last_operation();
  $_[1] = $value if not readonly($_[1]);
  return $error;
}

sub main {
  my $error = Lookup("Foo",undef); # Fails
  process_error($error) if $error < 0;
  
  my $error = Lookup("Foo"); # Fails
  process_error($error) if $error < 0;
  
  my $dummyvar = "";
  my $error = Lookup("Foo", $dummyvar); # Succeeds
  process_error($error) if $error < 0;
}
```

If the developer just needs to check the error code that is returned, he/she might use "undef" as the second argument, or leave that argument out, instead of creating a dummy variable just to avoid the Perl error "Modification of a read-only value attempted at  line .".

On the other hand, if one tries the following then it also doesn't have the desired behavior:

```
sub Lookup2 {
  # Get a value from a table, file, or database, using the label in $_[0].
  # Set $_[1] to that value if that parameter is writable.
  # Return an error code or a success code.
  my $value = get_value_from_somewhere($_[0]);
  my $error = get_error_from_last_operation();
  $_[1] = $value if defined $_[1] and not readonly($_[1]);
  return $error;
}

sub main2 {
  my $error = Lookup2("Foo",undef); # Succeeds
  process_error($error) if $error < 0;
  
  my $error = Lookup2("Foo"); # Succeeds
  process_error($error) if $error < 0;
  
  my $result;
  my $error = Lookup2("Foo", $result); # Fails
  process_error($error) if $error < 0;
}
```

In this second version an attempt to get a value into $result fails because that variable has an undefined value when Lookup2 is called.

Is there a solution for the Lookup routine that would allow the following calls to work as one would expect?

```
my $x; $error = Lookup("Foo", $x);       # Sets $x with a value.
my $y = ""; $error = Lookup("Foo", $y);  # Sets $y with a value.
$error = Lookup("Foo");                  # Just returns $error.
$error = Lookup("Foo", undef);           # Just returns $error.
```

Of course, the second argument could always require a reference to a scalar variable, but it would be nice to support the non-reference syntax for the second argument (i.e. by setting $_[1]).